# Passing many arguments to input in python 3. Number guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I just started learning programming in Python with Michael Dawson's book and cannot think of a way to get around a problem with an exercise. It's supposed to be a 'guess a number' game where the computer tries to guess a number I chose.

```
import random
print("Pick any number between 1-100 and I'll try to guess it")
x = 1
y = 100
tries = 0
answer = "whatever"

while answer != "yes":
guess = random.randint(x, y)
answer = input("Is your number ", guess, "? Or is it 'lo'wer or 'hi'gher?")
if answer == "hi":
    x = guess + 1
if answer == "lo":
    y = guess - 1
tries += 1

print ("Got it! Your number is ", los, "! It took me ", tries, " Tries! :)")
input("End")
```

As you probably expect, this is what python feeds me back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Documents/python/numbers.py", line 11, in <module>
answer = input("Is your number ", guess, "? Or is it 'lo'wer or 'hi'gher?")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

So I know that I shouldn't expect`input` to take more than 1 argument but I can't really grasp what to do with this. Any friendly kick towards the solution will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: If one of the questions solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted using gray checkmark below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) expects a single string as mentioned in the docs

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline.

Use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) instead

```
answer= input("Is your number {}? Or is it 'lo'wer or 'hi'gher?".format(guess))
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It works. I still don't get why but I hope it will come clear further down the road.

Comment: @MichałJasiński Just read the docs! they are very clear. All the best!

Comment: `"One Plus Two Is {}".format("three")` ... `format` is a method that strings have that will allow you to ...format... your string and replace stuff.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I unaccepted your answer. Fixing it right away!

Answer (score 1):

You can add one line above input and change the input function call a bit.

```
import random
print("Pick any number between 1-100 and I'll try to guess it")
x = 1
y = 100
tries = 0
answer = "whatever"

while answer != "yes":
  guess = random.randint(x, y)
  input_message = "Is your number ", guess, "? Or is it 'lo'wer or 'hi'gher?"
  answer = input(input_message)

  if answer == "hi":
    x = guess + 1
  if answer == "lo":
    y = guess - 1
  tries += 1

print ("Got it! Your number is ", los, "! It took me ", tries, " Tries! :)")
input("End")
```

Comment: This method seems way more logical to me. Is there any big difference between this and using 'format' like in other replies? Is there a some kind of widely used standard approach or whatever fits best?

Comment: `format` is the industrial standard way of doing it. This is a good way too for learners (+1 from me)

Comment: Yes, Rao is correct. This is just a way to understand how python works as a beginner. But with experience as Rao suggested 'format' is the way.